# "No Java virtual machine has been registered" error when using "mediacodec"

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec, arm64

I successfully cross-compiled FFmpeg with "mediacodec" (developed in Java) library for aarch64 ARM architecture under Android OS.
When I try to run FFmpeg on Android without "mediacodec", it works just fine.
However, when I run it with "mediacodec" option I got an error:
"No Java virtual machine has been registered"
Here is the command line I used:
 ./ffmpeg -vcodec hevc_mediacodec -i jellyfish-20-mbps-hd-hevc.mkv -f null out.null

1) is is the problem of JRE?
2) if so, could someone guide me to enable JRE on Android, or cross-compile it?

Actually, I tried many times to cross-compile "openjdk" for aarch64 but none works.

Answer (score 1):

MediaCodec can only run in context of an Android app. This means that your code should be compiled into a JNI shared library. You cannot use it from command line.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Is there another way to do video decoding on Android system without displaying the content? because my purpose is to evaluate the performance of 
 the decoding process in terms of time and power consumption.

Comment: You can have an app that will display nothing. Or update the progress meter one in a while. This should not effect your measurements.